# Is it possible to get "ideal" full-text relevance for two constant(same) samples?

Tags: mysql

Full-text `MATCH` gives a relative relevance for all records in an indexed table. However, I make the decision based on a similarity level (let's say <70% is insufficient to consider it as a match) between tested sample and constant sample (which I compare against).

Previously I used Levenshtein Distance to get percentage coefficient of how much two samples are similar. But this method showed itself as incredibly inefficient for my dataset.

What I'd like to do is to get a relevance coefficient for sample matched to itself to consider it as 100% relevance

I tried queries like:

```
SELECT
    samples.`name`,
    MATCH(samples.`name`)
        AGAINST ('Constant sample' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE),
    MATCH (perfectSample.sample)
        AGAINST ('Constant sample' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
FROM
    samples,
    (SELECT 'Constant sample' as sample) as perfectSample
```

But `embedded from` does not support full-text match (My idea was: since `MyISAM` table must not have `FULLTEXT` index, It is possible to achieve it this way).

So the actual question is: Is it possible to obtain `FULLTEXT` relevance for 2 constant values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here is what I managed to do. Maybe someone will get any use of it.
First of all, samples should be inserted to a `InnoDB` (important) table that has `FULLTEXT` index on a field that has to be `MATCH`ed

After this it is necessary to fetch all values (samples) that will be compared with.

```
SELECT * FROM samples
```

Next, these fetched fields need to be `MATCH`ed against themselves. It is better to put a WHERE clause so that a field is not matched to anything else.

```
SELECT
    samples.value,
    MATCH (samples.value) AGAINST (:fetchedVal)
WHERE samples.value = :fetchedVal
```

This will give a relevancy for each sample `AGAINST` itself.

Note: It is important to use `InnoDB` because `MyISAM` `MATCH` with only one row will produce result that will not be useful. For example: same query can produce relevancy value `40.1511 for InnoDB` and `3 for MyISAM`.
This is due to the way of how word uniqueness is calculated. You can read more about this [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

And that's it. Second query will give (in my opinion) 100% relevancy, which can be used to determine similarity level between this sample and others

It is a bit dirty, but that's the only option that worked for me. And since no one suggested anything else (better) I will keep this as an answer until better solution is found